# Calling another content script from the background script which runs on different tab

Tags: google-chrome

I am working on a Chrome extension to automate some tasks. I have content `script1` which is called by the pop-up menu. It calls the background script which switches to the next tab and then calls a new content script which alerts some data. The issue is, that the content script called by background page alert the data on the previous page while I want it to alert the data on a new switched tab. I am stuck with it, could anyone help me please?

Comment: It will be not possible to help you without code/scripts examples which you use...

Comment: Please read [ask]. Then [edit] your question and add the code you've tried so far. What happens when you run it? What did you expect to happen instead? Any errors?